# VBA convert Excel Style Column Name (with 52 charset) to original number

Tags: c++, vba, excel

I have a c++ program that takes an integer and convert it to lower and uppercase alphabets, similar to what excel does to convert column index to column number but also including lower case letters.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
string ConvertNum(unsigned long v)
{
    char const digits[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    size_t const base = sizeof(digits) - 1;
    char result[sizeof(unsigned long)*CHAR_BIT + 1];
    char* current = result + sizeof(result);
    *--current = '\0';

    while (v != 0) {
        v--;
        *--current = digits[v % base];
        v /= base;
    }
    return current;
}

// for testing


int main()
{
    cout<< ConvertNum(705);

    return 0;
}
```

I need the vba function to reverse this back to the original number. I do not have a lot of experience with C++ so I can not figure out a logic to reverse this in vba. Can anyone please help.

**Update 1:** I don't need already written code, just some help in the logic to reverse it. I'll try to convert the logic into code myself.

**Update 2:** Base on the wonderful explanation and help provided in the answer, it's clear that the code is not converting the number to a usual base52, it is misleading. So I have changed the function name to eliminate the confusion for future readers.

Comment: I code for money, but help for free. You're not experienced in C++ - what do you use? Write pseudocode! Anything!

Comment: I have done some beginner vba code for excel and willing to learn more on vba, but can't actually understand what is happening in the above program to figure out a logic to reverse it.

Comment: If you are not familiar with C++ notation, read about how to do base conversion somewhere else and write your own code from that. Some hints: `v % base` is the last digit when written in that base. By dividing by `base` you "cut off" the last digit because you're doing integer calculation so the rational part gets dropped. Your code just does that over and over with minimal lines/characters of  code (and comments!).
Thinking about what happens in base 10 might be helpful. (v mod 10 is obviously the last decimal digit of v)

Comment: Can we assume that in the least significant place the lower case *a* corresponds to **0** and the lower case *b* corresponds to **1**, etc. ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - Upper case _A_ is **1** and so on, lower case _a_ is **27**. The total index starts from 1 to 52. 52 in the above test program return lowercase _z_.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct: Thanks for the hint, I'll try to read more on this when I get home. I was just asked (at work) if I can reverse it,

Comment: Then how is a decimal **0** represented in the base-52 system ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - The count starts from **1** and runs up to **52**. From what I am able to under stand from   arcadeprecinct's hint above, it works based on the combination of letters. Similar to what excel does for it's column numbers. For **53**, it's _AA_ and **50** is _x_. Hope that makes sense

Comment: It turns out I was completely wrong, the code is indeed converting 53 to AA.  See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**  The character string format being translated to decimal by the code described below is NOT a standard base-52 schema.  The schema does not include **0** or any other digits.  Therefore this code should not be used, as is, to translate a standard base-52 value to decimal.

---

O.K. this is based on converting a **single character** based on its position in a long string.  the string is:

```
chSET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

The *InStr()* function tells us the **A** is in position **1** and the **Z** is in position **26** and that **a** is in position **27**.  All characters get converted the same way.

I use this rather than *Asc()* because *Asc()* has a gap between the upper and lower case letters.

The least significant character's value gets multiplied by 52^0
The next character's value gets multiplied by 52^1
The third character's value gets multiplied by 52^3, etc.  The code:

```
Public Function deccimal(s As String) As Long
    Dim chSET As String, arr(1 To 52) As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, K As Long, CH As String

    chSET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    deccimal = 0
    L = Len(s)
    K = 0
    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        deccimal = deccimal + InStr(1, chSET, CH) * (52 ^ K)
        K = K + 1
    Next i
End Function
```

Some examples:

[image]

---

***NOTE:***

This is NOT the way bases are usually encoded.  Usually bases start with a **0** and allow **0** in any of the encoded value's positions.  In all my previous *UDF()*'s similar to this one, the first character in `chSET` is a **0** and I have to use `(InStr(1, chSET, CH) - 1) * (52 ^ K)`

Comment: This seems to be the correct way to convert column names to integers. However it's not actually base 52 (or 26) because there is no zero (as you noted in your comment to the original question) and the digits go up to the  base. So z as the last position would be the first value as A in the second position. (52*52^0 and 1*52^1)

Comment: @arcadeprecinct  you are correct about the zero, but *Praveen* is only concerned about mapping positive values in the fashion that he indicated.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys _Gary'sStudent_ and _arcadeprecinct_. I also managed to figure out the logic on paper, but _Gary'sStudent_ was quicker to actually write a function and show a demo. Thanks a lot once again!!.

I used the following link to understand the base conversion:
http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55730.html

Comment: Base 52 characters should be numbers 0..51 (similar to base 10 numbers 0..9)  So furmula should be `deccimal = deccimal + (InStr(1, chSET, CH) - 1) * (52 ^ K)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen  **You are completely correct** for standard bases like binary or octal, or hexadecimal, but this is NOT a standard base................. *Praveen* did not want to incorporate a **0**, so there is no zero place-holder like **JA0MES** or **A0**

Comment: @chrisneilsen  The only encodement I have ever encountered without a **0** is Roman Numerals.

Comment: @Gary I don't think Praveen knows what he wants.

Comment: @Gary besides, my reading of the OPs posted code (that he wants to reverse) is that it is coding base52 (ie 0..51 digits).  Op has already stated he can't read that code.

Comment: @chrisneilsen  I based my code on *Praveen*'s examples in his last comment to his question rather than the code that he posted

Comment: @Gary I'm more concerned about the value of the Q/A to SO.  A Q that asks _VBA convert base 52 number to base 10 based on charset_ that has an (accepted) answer that is _not_ base52 is harmfull.  I think you should highlight at the top of your answer that it is not base52

Comment: @chrisneilsen actually this is the reverse of OPs code. Notice the v-- within the loop. That makes it not really base 52 so I think the name of the function is a bad choice, especially without comments.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - The answers from _Garry's Student_ & _arcadeprecinct_ made me realize that this is not standard base 52 conversion. I have edited the original question to remove reference to base 52.

Comment: @chrisneilsen  the question confused me as well..........I could not match what the Poster wanted until I realized this is non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

Gary's Student provided a good and easy to understand way to get the number from what I call "Excel style base 52" and this is what you wanted.

However this is a little different from the usual base 52. I'll try to explain the difference to regular base 52 and its conversion. There might be an easier way but this is the best I could come up with that also explains the code you provided.

As an example: The number zz..zz means 51*(1 + 52 + 52^2 + ... 52^(n-1)) in regular base 52 and 52*(1 + 52 + 52^2 + ... 52^(n-1)) in Excel style base 52. So Excel style get's higher number with fewer digits. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(52%5En-1)%2F51) is how much that difference is based on number of digits. How is this possible? It uses leading zeros so 1, 01, 001 etc are all different numbers. Why don't we do this normally? It would mess up the easy arithmetic of the usual system.

We can't just shift all the digits by one after the base change and we can't just substract 1 before the base change to counter the fact that we start at 1 instead of 0. I'll outline the problem with base 10. If we'd use Excel style base 10 to number the columns, we would have to count like "0, 1, 2, ..., 9, 00, 01, 02, ...". On the first glance it looks like we just have to shift the digits so we start counting at 1 but this only works up to the 10th number.

```
1  2 .. 10  11 .. 20  21  ..  99  100 .. 110  111 //normal counting
0  1 ..  9  00 .. 09  10  ..  88   89 ..  99  000 //excel style counting
```

You notice that whenever we add a new digit we shift again. To counter that, we have to do a shift by 1 before calculating each digit, not shift the digit after calculating it. (This only makes a difference if we're at 52^k) Note that we still assign A to 0, B to 1 etc.

Normally what you would do to change bases is looping with something like

```
nextDigit = x mod base //determining the last digit
x = x/base             //removing the last digit
//terminate if x = 0
```

However now it is

```
x = x - 1
nextDigit = x mod base
x = x/base
//terminate if x = 0
```

So x is decremented by 1 first! Let's do a quick check for x=52:

Regular base 52:

```
nextDigit = x mod 52 //52 mod 52 = 0 so the next digit is A
x = x/52 //x is now 1
//next iteration
nextDigit = x mod 52 //1 mod 52 = 1 so the next digit is B
x = x/52 //1/52 = 0 in integer arithmetic
//terminate because x = 0
//result is BA
```

Excel style:

```
x = x-1 //x is now 51
nextDigit = x mod 52 //51 mod 52 = 51 so the next digit is z
x = x/52 //51/52 = 0 in integer arithmetic
//terminate because x=0
//result is z
```

It works!

### Part 2: Your C++ code

Now for let's read your code:

- `x % y` means x mod y
- When you do calculations with integers, the result will be an integer which is achieved by rounding down. So 39/10 will produce 3 etc.

  - `x++` and `++x` both increment x by 1.

You can use this in other statements to save a line of code. `x++` means x is incremented after the statement is evaluated and `++x` means it is incremented before the statement is evaluated

```
y=f(x++);
```

is the same as

```
y = f(x);
x = x + 1;
```

while

```
y=f(++x);
```

is the same as

```
x = x + 1; 
y = f(x);
```

This goes the same way for `--`

- `Char* p` creates a pointer to a `char`.

A pointer points to a certain location in memory. If you change the pointer, it points to a different location. E.g. doing `p--` moves the pointer one to the left. To read or write the value that is saved at the location, use `*p`. E.g. `*p="a";` "a" is written to the memory location that `p` points at. `*p--="a";` "a" is written to the memory but the pointer is moved to the left afterwards so *p is now whatever is in the memory left of "a".

- strings are just arrays of type char.

The end of a string is always '\0' if the computer reads a string it continues until it finds '\0'

This is hopefully enough to understand the code. Here it is

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
string base52(unsigned long v)
{
    char const digits[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //The digits. (Arrays start at 0)
    size_t const base = sizeof(digits) - 1; //The base, based on the digits that were given
    char result[sizeof(unsigned long)*CHAR_BIT + 1]; //The array that holds the answer 
        //sizeof(unsigned long)*CHAR_BIT is the number of bits of an unsigned long
        //which means it is the absolute longest that v can be in any base.
        //The +1 is to hold the terminating character '\0' 
    char* current = result + sizeof(result); //This is a pointer that is supposed to point to the next digit. It points to the first byte after the result array (because its start + length)
        //(i.e. it will go through the memory from high to low)
    *--current = '\0';  //The pointer gets moved one to the left (to the last char of result and the terminating char is added
        //the pointer has to be moved to the left first because it was actually pointing to the first byte after the result.

    while (v != 0) {  //loop until v is zero (until there are no more digits left.
        v--; //v = v - 1. This is the important part that does the 1 -> A part
        *--current = digits[v % base];  // the pointer is moved one to the left and the corresponding digit is saved
        v /= base; //the last digit is dropped
    }
    return current; //current is returned, which points at the last saved digit. The rest of the result array (before current) is not used.
}

// for testing


int main()
{
    cout<< base52(705);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you **very much** ...................your explanation is WAY better than mine.

Comment: Well it isn't actually what OP wanted, that was provided by your answer but I thought it was worth explaining what happens because of the confusion. In my opinion the naming C function is misleading and the minimalist code and lack of commenting make it difficult to see what is happening.

Comment: I think that c++ in general is a language that makes it easy to code, but hard to read........but maybe that's just me!

Comment: I agree. If you're not familiar with pointers and the syntax it's near impossible to read. `*--` looks weird as hell as a unary operator in front of a variable while `i = i-1; result[i]=...` could probably be understood with basic knowledge in any language.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct - **Thanks a lot for detailed explanation**. I got what I wanted earlier, but this is step-by-step explanation of the concepts and the difference from the normal base conversion. **You Rock..** Cheers !!